# Generating pseudoRandom number less than 7 in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

Which one is correct and why??

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: depends if you want 0 to be a number that can be returned or not

Comment: I tried it however I don't see any difference.

Comment: Actually the first one makes more sense, that's because your are applying `Math.random()` and immediately multiplying it per 7, the other formula in adding plus 1 to the already randomized value, no it's not random at all.

Comment: @AdriSolid: All that that does is shift the final number. It doesn't change the overall randomness.

Comment: *"I tried it however I don't see any difference."* Replace `Math.random()` with `0`. Do you see a difference now?

Answer (score 0):

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

because Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive),  and 1 (exclusive):

description : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp

Comment: With `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)`, the number `6` will never be generated.